# Unable to move a question to meta

Tags: support, status-bydesign, specific-question, migration, meta

I came across a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31/essential-reading-learning-resources-for-the-code-reviewer?rq=1). I think this should be moved to meta but I was unable to flag it.

**EDIT**

The reason I added this question was that it seems to be on topic on Meta Code Review than the main site as per the current posts on community bulletin.

If not there is a bug in Stack Exchange. The locked posts should be removed from every question list. But it is being shown in the related questions in [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54351/code-duplication-for-just-an-if-condition) question.

[Original image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKSWD.png)

[image: Red Circle here!]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that the question is off-topic on the main site. It is better (though not perfect) on the meta site. The problem is that the post is old, and questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated (and that is what would be needed even between main and meta sites).

So the choice is to either close, delete, lock, or reopen the post.

Locking seems most useful because the post still exists, and is searchable, but is no longer active.

If you have suggestions for another alternative, please speak up.

Comment: I did not know about the 60 days limit. I guess I just need a report a bug to stackexchange for the question appearing in the Related questions. How can I do that?

Comment: @AseemBansal - Edit this question to state what you think the bug is, and I will tag it as such. The SE folk patrol the various meta sites and will process it.

Comment: Actually, you can tag it as bug yourself.

Comment: @AseemBansal: If you'd still like to report this, it may be best to post a separate question here, now that you know about the 60-day limit.  As rolfl has mentioned, someone from SE will eventually come across it.

Answer (score 4):

We recognize that that question is off-topic for Code Review.  A moderator has already put a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/148099) on it.

Comment: Please see the updated question.